# Filling field according to value of another field with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am very ill at ease with Python. I am working on ArcGIS 10.3. I am working on a table in a gdb.

I want to fill an empty field of this table with an expression (words) according to the value of a second field in the same table.

In my case, if my second field contain the word "roadway", I want to fill the empty field cells councerned by this expression "route à deux chaussées".
I know that accents are not good in programming but I need to fill my field with (french...).

My script is below:

```
import arcpy

fc = "D:/TESTS_TOP25/POUR_SDC/ROUTIER_TRAITEMENT/DONNEES.gdb"

#field'sname
field1 = "NATURE"
field2 = "symbology"

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    if field1 == "roadway"
        field2 == "route à deux chaussée"
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: There are a few errors in your code as posted: you give the path to the geodatabase, but not a feature class in that geodatabase; `field2 ==` isn't the right way to assign the column, but if it were, it would be `field2 =`; there's no `:` to follow the `if` statement; double backslashes are best for Windows paths in Python, or use the os.path module.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, using the feature class "UneFC" inside DONNEES.gdb, and using the newer arcpy.da.UpdateCursor().

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- # Should handle the French characters.

import arcpy

fc = "D:\\TESTS_TOP25\\POUR_SDC\\ROUTIER_TRAITEMENT\\DONNEES.gdb\\UneFC"

fields = ("NATURE", "symbology")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "roadway": # if NATURE is "roadway"...
            row[1] = "route à deux chaussée" # Voila votre traduction ;)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```